# Circular reference in EF Code-First

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In EF 6.2.0 Code-First, after the latest data model extension, I have a circular reference in my data model:

```
public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    [ForeignKey("OwnerId")]
    public Player Owner { get; set; }
}
```

The "Owner" is the person who entered the record into the database and is allowed to make changes to it.

```
public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? AddressId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LocationId")]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Location Address { get; set; }
}
```

The "Address" is the current home address of the player. (Null for players whose home addresses are not known)

Now, when creating the migration after the `Address` and `AddressId` fields have been added, I get the error message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types ... **The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured** using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

I think it is because EF tries to match the references into a single two-way reference, which is not what I want to achieve. Instead, I need two independent one-to-many references. The [Microsoft page on Fluent API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591620(v=vs.113).aspx) does not help me there.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How about decorating `Owner` in `Location` by `[Required]` ?

Comment: configure the navigation properties to be inverses of each other, and configure one end as principal/dependent.

Comment: Configure 2 *unidirectional* relationships with the help of parameterless `WithMany()`

Comment: @Hey24sheep I have not found any DTO file (whatever that is) in the project folder.

Comment: @Aria This causes the error "Location_Owner_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Location_Owner_Source' in relationship 'Location_Owner'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'."

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I don't understand, can you break down the steps a little?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fluent API for modeling these two one-to-many associations is:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Player>()
    .HasOptional(p => p.Address)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.AddressId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Location>()
    .HasRequired(l => l.Owner)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(l => l.OwnerId);
```

As you see, the `WithMany()` method can be used without parameters to indicate that the association doesn't have a collection navigation property on the other end. I think that's an omission in the documentation page you refer to.